# Pull down updates when user click on updates

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

Hello people please help me with this! what i want to achieve is similar to twitter update notification bar that displays the number of new tweets and when you click on it; it drops the latest tweets on the previous tweets. i have been banging my head over this for days now, Here is what i tried.

```
//feed.php
<?php
session_start();
        $cxn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','my_db');
        $query = "SELECT insertion_time FROM feeds ORDER BY insertion_time DESC LIMIT 0,1";
    $result = mysqli_query($cxn, $query) or die (mysqli_error($cxn));
    $latest_feed =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $_SESSION['latest_id'] = $latest_feed['insertion_time'];
        $latest_news = $_SESSION['latest_id']; 

 echo $check = <<<JS_SCRIPT
    <script>
         interval = setInterval(function(){
            check_update($latest_news);
        },5000);
    </script>
JS_SCRIPT;
?>
<script src='jquery.js'></script>
<script>
    function check_update(old_feed)
    {
        $.post('server.php',{get_num_update: old_feed},function(data){
                $("#update_bar").html(data);
            }); //checks for number of updates


        $.post('server.php',{retrieve_update: old_feed},function(data){
                $("#hidden_div").html(data);
            }); //retrieves the update into a div 
    }
      $(function(){
       $("#update_bar").click(function(){
          $("#hidden_div").prependTo("#news_feed_container").fadeIn(500);
        });
 });

</script>


//server.php
if(isset($_POST['get_num_update']) && !empty($_POST['get_num_update']) && is_numeric($_POST['get_num_update']))
{
$old_feed = $_POST['get_num_update'];

$query = "SELECT id FROM feeds WHERE insertion_time > $old_feed ORDER BY  insertion_time DESC";
$exec = mysqli_query($cxn, $query) or die(mysqli_error($cxn));
    $num_updates = mysqli_num_rows($exec);
    echo ($num_updates > 0) ? $num_updates.' new updates' : '';

}
  if(isset($_POST['retrieve_update']) && !empty($_POST['retrieve_update']) && is_numeric($_POST['retrieve_update']))
{ 

      while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($exec))
     {
        extract($result);

        echo <<<HTML
            //inserting the variable into html
   HTML;


      }

  }
```

//
when the user clicks on the update_bar div which will be displaying something like '5 new updates' i want the update to pull down the latest feed from the hidden div, so everything doesn't really work as i would expect someone please help me out

Comment: Need more details to help you. Which steps are not working ? What error do you have ? What is the type of `insertion_time` ? would be a good starting point.

Comment: am not getting any error but i have a logic error in my code.. basically the first query is to select the insertion time of all feeds from the database and order it DESC, insertion_time contains php strtotime function value of when the feeds were inserted into the db.  so am getting only the latest feed and assigning it to variable, then i echo some javascript code that will call a function every 5 seconds to check if there are updates it does work my problem is when it return number of updates how do i display them, and then start checking for update based on the ones i just got. thanks

Comment: In `feed.php`, i suppose you also have HTML code with `#update_bar`, `#news_feed_container`, `#hidden_div`. If you do not have any error, at least `#hidden_div` should be added at the beginning of `#news_feed_container` at each click on `#update_bar`. Is it the case?

Comment: yes exactly `#hidden_div` has data it has retrieved so the prepending does work! but the `#update_bar` needs to be updated because the user is now viewing the latest feed it was notifying. so i guess i have to clear the interval and recall the `check_update()` function with the `insertion_time` of the latest feed the user is viewing just as i did initially ... thanks :) ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested, but it should approximately work...

```
//feed.php
<?php
session_start();
        $cxn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','my_db');
        $query = "SELECT insertion_time FROM feeds ORDER BY insertion_time DESC LIMIT 0,1";
    $result = mysqli_query($cxn, $query) or die (mysqli_error($cxn));
    $latest_feed =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $_SESSION['latest_id'] = $latest_feed['insertion_time'];
        $latest_news = $_SESSION['latest_id']; 

 echo $check = <<<JS_SCRIPT
    <script>
         // made the parameter of check_update a js variable and not hard coded in PHP
         var latest_new=$latest_news;
         // add a temp js variable for the last feed received (but not displayed)
         var last_received=$latest_news;
         interval = setInterval(function(){
            check_update(latest_news);
        },5000);
    </script>
JS_SCRIPT;
?>
<script src='jquery.js'></script>
<script>
    function check_update(old_feed)
    {
        // change your AJAX request to deal with JSON data and received several informations (number of new feed, insertion time of the last one)
        $.post('server.php',{get_num_update: old_feed},function(data){
                $("#update_bar").html(data.number_recents+" new updates.");
                last_received=data.last_time;
            },'json');
        $.post('server.php',{retrieve_update: old_feed},function(data){
            $("#hidden_div").html(data);
        }); //retrieves the update into a div
    }
      $(function(){
       $("#update_bar").click(function(){
          $("#hidden_div").prependTo("#news_feed_container").fadeIn(500);
          latest_new=last_received;
        });
 });

</script>


//server.php
if(isset($_POST['get_num_update']) && !empty(get_num_update']))
{
// header to serve JSON data
header('application/json');
$old_feed = $_POST['get_num_update'];
// request the number of new feed and the mst recent insertion time
$query = "SELECT count(*) as number,max(insertion_time) as last_time FROM feeds WHERE insertion_time > $old_feed ORDER BY  insertion_time DESC";
$exec = mysqli_query($cxn, $query) or die(mysqli_error($cxn));
    $feed_info =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($exec);
    //write the JSON data
    echo '{"number_recents":'.$feed_info['number'].',"last_time":'.last_time.'}';

} else if(isset($_POST['retrieve_update']) && !empty($_POST['retrieve_update']) && is_numeric($_POST['retrieve_update']))
{ 

      while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($exec))
     {
        extract($result);

        echo <<<HTML
            //inserting the variable into html
   HTML;


      }

  }
```